# MTA-STS TLS Reporting - why is no policy found for Google but Microsoft and other domains find and report success for new sts policy. 100% success

Tags: email, smtp, email-validation, starttls, dmarc

I am 2+ weeks after deploying MTA-STS policy in testing mode. I am getting TLS Reporting from several domains.  Google Inc reports “no policy found”. All other domains find and apply the sts policy. All domains report 100% success.

I’m stumped why Google Inc isn’t recognizing the policy. No error reports. 100% success.

Dmarcian TLS inspector shows all ok.
Policy Text and url:

```
https://example.com/.well-known/mta-sts.txt :
version: STSv1 
Mode: testing
mx: mydomain-com.mail.protection.outlook.c…
max_age: 600
```

Btw.  There are no restrictions in .htaccess and can see successful 200 for domains that access the policy url, including Google.

POSSIBLE UPDATE: I noticed an update on an article [MTA-STS explained](https://www.uriports.com/blog/mta-sts-explained/) that "Google will only process policies with a max_age higher than 86000 seconds. Policies with a max_age of 86000 or lower will be ignored and a daily no-policy-found report will be sent if TLS-RPT is enabled ."

I’ve modified the .wellknown/mta-sts.txt file to set max_age above the min 86000 suggested in the article and to 86400 so it is consistent with the google guidance below. Also see google support answer (2. Create an MTA-STS policy - Google Workspace Admin Help) that says the max_age value must be between 86400 (1 day) and 31557600 (about 1 year).

ANSWER:  Google will only process policies with a max_age higher than 86000 seconds. Policies with a max_age of 86000 or lower will be ignored and a daily no-policy-found report will be sent if TLS-RPT is enabled ."

Comment: Is it working now with the updated `max_age`? If not, can you share your domain so that I can check your MTA-STS setup myself?

Comment: yes.  by setting the max_age to 86000 fixed my problem with google  Any value between  86400 (1 day) and 31557600 (about 1 year) works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .wellknown/mta-sts.txt file set max_age >= 86400 so it is consistent with the google guidance.

Google's (Create an MTA-STS policy - Google Workspace Admin Help) states that the max_age value must be between 86400 (1 day) and 31557600 (about 1 year).
In my testing over the past few weeks, Google reported "no policy found" when the max_age is lower than that range and when max_age is at least 86400, correctly found the policy.